# How to add custom field in checkout step

Tags: onepage-checkout

I'm trying to find a tutorial which show me how to add custom field to one page checkout page in magento 1.9.1 version. 
I tried to use [This Turorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/) but it's quite old and not working, i see the field and everything but my custom field in database is empty. 
Maybe somebody have working tutorial for magento 1.9  ?

Thanks for all replies